# What is the difference?

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and I only try out some of the codes I found on Jquery API documentation. I have found two different way to achieve the same result.

Could someone explain what is the difference between the two codes?

The first:

```
$(".size1").click(function() {
    $(".size1").toggleClass("size2");    
});
```

And the second:

```
$("div.size1").on({
    click: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("size2");
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two significant differences:

1. Your first one will handle clicks on *any* element with the class `size1` (because you're using `$(".size1")`), whereas your second one will only handle clicks on `div` elements with that class (because you're using `$("div.size1")`).
2. Your first will toggle `size2` on **all** `.size1` elements when **any** of them is clicked, because it does `$(".size1").toggleClass("size2")`. Your second will only toggle `size2` on the specific `.size1` that was clicked, because it does `$(this).toggleClass("size2")`, and `this` will refer to *just* the element that was clicked. (Well-spotted [JJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/jjj).)

The `on` vs. `click` thing isn't a significant difference. `click` (when you pass it a function) is just a shorthand for `on`, as [it says in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder!